# C++ | Linking together MinGW, wxWidgets, CMD.exe, Notepad

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, command-line-interface, wxwidgets

I have `C:\MinGW` and `C:\wxWidgets`. My wxWidgets is nicely installed and built. Im trying to compile a "Hello World" program in notepad using Command Line Prompt.

I can compile this `main.cpp` just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`

When I try to compile a wxWidgets simple line like this:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

g++ main.cpp
```

I get errors (wx/wx.h doesn't exist)

**What is the syntax to compile the program using the command line?**

I have tried `g++ -std=c++11 -Ic:/wxWidgets/include main.cpp`

and I still get errors. I am missing a lot of things. I have to compile with command line and without an IDE.

**Also, any explaination about `-I` or about what is linking / how to link, would be appreciated. I am new to C++**

Comment: what about a nice IDE?

Comment: I must not use IDE. It's about a homework

Comment: @marirena May be use a Makefile additionally then, or at least a shell script: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026331/what-is-the-purpose-of-creating-object-files-separately-and-then-linking-them-to) are some hints what to do. If that's a homework task, you already should have found some explanations how to correctly link additional libraries in your text book. Also have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), how to resolve linker errors in general.

Answer (score 0):

Even, or maybe especially, if you're new to something, reading [the documentation](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/docs/msw/install.txt#L458) is strongly recommended.