# Why do we describe build procedures with Makefiles instead of shell scripts?

Tags: shell, build, makefile, bsdmake

> **Remark** This is a variation on the question “[What is the purpose
>   of linking object files separately in a
>   Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26026331)” by user4076675 taking
>   a slightly different point of view. See also the corresponding [META
>   discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272227/should-questions-receiving-a-general-answer-edit-with-a-more-general-title).

Let us consider the classical case of a C project.  The `gcc` compiler
is able to compile and link programs in one step.  We can then easily
describe the build routine with a shell script:

```
case $1 in
    build)  gcc -o test *.c;;
    clean)  rm -f test;;
esac
# This script is intentionally very brittle, to keep
# the example simple.
```

However, it appears to be idiomatic to describe the build procedure
with a `Makefile`, involving extra steps to compile each compilation
unit to an object file and ultimately linking these files. The
corresponding GNU Makefile would be:

```
.PHONY: all

SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $<

all: default
default: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -o test $^

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

This second solution is arguable more involved than the simple shell
script we wrote before.  It as also a drawback, as it clutters the
source directory with object files.  So, why do we describe build
procedures with Makefiles instead of shell scripts?  At the hand of
the previous example, it seems to be a useless complication.

Comment: Still seems like a duplicate of [What is the purpose of creating object files separately and then linking them together in a Makefile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026331/what-is-the-purpose-of-creating-object-files-separately-and-then-linking-them-to) to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder See the discussion on META. Consensus attained here suggested, not to generalise the question, but rather, post the generalisation as a new question.

Comment: I did look. I don't see this as different enough, nor do I think seven people upvoting the answer you like defines "consensus." But it's just my take.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe you can then contribute your argumentation to the corresponding META discussion?

Comment: The above is as far into it as I feel the need to get.

Answer (score 2):

In the simple case where we compile and link three moderately sized
files, any approach is likely to be equally satisfying. I will
therefore consider the general case but many benefits of using
Makefiles are only important on larger projects.  Once we learned the
best tool which allows us to master complicated cases, we want to use
it in simple cases as well.

Let me highlight the ''benefits'' of using `make` instead of a simple
shell script for compilation jobs.  But first, I would like to make an
innocuous observation.

### The procedural paradigm of shell scripts is wrong for compilation-like jobs

Writing a Makefile is similar to writing a shell script with a slight
change of perspective.  In a shell script, we describe a procedural
solution to a problem: we can start to describe the whole procedure in
very abstract terms using undefined functions, and we refine this
description until we reached the most elementary level of description,
where a procedure is just a plain shell command.  In a Makefile, we do
not introduce any similar abstraction, but we focus on the files we
want to produce and how we can produce them.  This works well because
in UNIX, everything is a file, therefore each treatment is
accomplished by a *program* which reads its input data from *input
files*, do some computation and write the results in some *output
files*.

If we want to compute something complicated, we have to use a lot of
input files which are treated by programs whose outputs are used as
inputs to other programs, and so on until we have produced our final
files containing our result. If we translate the plan to prepare our
final file into a bunch of procedures in a shell script, then the
current state of the processing is made *implicit*: the plan executor
knows “where it is at” because it is executing a given procedure,
which implicitly guarantees that such and such computations were
already done, that is, that such and such intermediary files were
already prepared.  Now, which data describes “where the plan executor
is at”?

**Innocuous observation** *The data which describes “where the plan
executor is at” is precisely the set of intermediary files which
were already prepared, and this is exactly the data which is made
explicit when we write Makefiles.*

This innocuous observation is actually the conceptual difference
between shell scripts and Makefiles which explains all the advantages
of Makefiles over shell scripts in compilation jobs and similar jobs.
Of course, to fully appreciate these advantages, we have to write
*correct* Makefiles, which might be hard for beginners.

### Make makes it easy to continue an interrupted task where it was at

When we describe a compilation job with a Makefile, we can easily
interrupt it and resume it later.  This is a consequence of the
*innocuous observation*.  A similar effect can only be achieved with
considerable efforts in a shell script, while it is just built in
`make`.

### Make makes it easy to work with several builds of a project

You observed that Makefiles will clutter the source tree with object
files. But Makefiles can actually be parametrised to store these
object files in a dedicated directory.  I work with [BSD Owl](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl/releases/tag/v3.0.0-20141203)
macros for [bsdmake](/questions/tagged/bsdmake) and use

```
MAKEOBJDIR='/usr/home/michael/obj${.CURDIR:S@^/usr/home/michael@@}'
```

so that all object files end under `~/obj` and do not pollute my
sources. See this
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116685/how-to-write-a-makefile-using-different-directories-for-targets-and-sources/25953462#25953462)
for more details.

Advanced Makefiles allow us to have simultaneously several directories
containing several builds of a project with distinct compilation
options. For instance, with distinct features enabled, or debug
versions, etc. This is also consequence of the *innocuous observation*
that Makefiles are actually articulated around the set of intermediary
files. This technique is illustrated in the [testsuite of BSD Owl](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl/tree/master/testsuite/langc/test_complex).

### Make makes it easy to parallelise builds

We can easily build a program in parallel since this is a standard
function of many versions of `make`. This is also consequence of the
*innocuous observation*: because “where the plan executor is at” is an
explicit data in a Makefile, it is possible for `make` to reason about
it.  Achieving a similar effect in a shell script would require a
great effort.

The parallel mode of any version of `make` will only work correctly if
the dependances are correctly specified.  This might be quite
complicated to achieve, but [bsdmake](/questions/tagged/bsdmake) has *the* feature which
literally anhilates the problem. It is called the
[META](http://www.crufty.net/help/sjg/bmake-meta-mode.htm) mode.  It
uses a first, non-parallel pass, of a compilation job to compute
*actual* dependencies by monitoring file access, and uses this
information in later parallel builds.

### Makefiles are easily extensible

Because of the special perspective — that is, as another consequence
of the *innocuous observation* — used to write Makefiles, we can
easily extend them by hooking into all aspects of our build system.

For instance, if we decide that all our database I/O boilerplate code
should be written by an automatic tool, we just have to write in the
Makefile which files should the automatic tool use as inputs to write
the boilerplate code. Nothing less, nothing more. And we can add this
description pretty much where we like, `make` will get it
anyway. Doing such an extension in a shell script build would be
harder than necessary.

This extensibility ease is a great incentive for Makefile code reuse.